An unscrewing of Neron-Severi group
I am reading Tate's paper "On Conjecture of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer and a geometric analog" ,  I want to know the proof of some results about Neron-Severi group , which is used in Tate's paper without any reference , especially "an unsrewing of NS". Precise statement is as following:(all notation is the same as Tate's paper)
k= finite field , X= geometrically Connected projective algebraic surface over k
, V=an irreducible algebraic curve proper smooth over k,with function field K. NS denote Neron-Severi group. A= jacobian of generic fibre
$f:X\rightarrow V$ is a smooth surjective k-morphism, with connected geometric fibre and smooth generic fibre.
then $\frac{NS(X)_{deg\ zero\ on\ fibre}}{f^{*}(NS(V))}$ is equal $A(K)+\sum_{v}(NS)_v$
, up to torsion.
here $v$ sum over closed point of V , $(NS)_v$ denote quotient of free abelian group generated by the irreducible component of $f^{-1}(v)$ by the cycle $f^{-1}(v)$.
How to prove this?You can give me any reference seems to related with this.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I didn't know it was screwed... Anyway, this is a version of what is sometimes called "Shioda--Tate formula". That name more commonly applies to a fibration whose fibres are genus 1, but you might find some relevant results starting with that prompt.

I learnt this theory (the Shioda-Tate formula and its proof) from a paper by Shioda, I think it may have been "An Explicit Algorithm for Computing the Picard Number of Certain Algebraic Surfaces," but I'm not 100% sure. In any case, Shioda explains it very well, and probably his arguments can be easily extended from genus 1 fibrations to the general case. The main ideas behind it were pretty simple anyway. I'm sorry for being vague, but it's a pretty long time ago and I no longer work in this area...

finally I found a good reference for this:
Mordell-Weil lattices for higher genus fibration over a curve
by Tetsuji Shioda
